# PWA in ios, prevent to add home screen multiple time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, polymer-1.0, progressive-web-apps

PWA app is not working properly in ios like, in android if you add an app into your homescreen next time it wouldn't allow you to add it will show the message like app is already installed in your phone but in ios it is allowing to add n number of time which is not good if user have app already then why they will add it multiple time.

Can anyone pls help me on this?
Can we resolve this issue?
Please suggest something like is it a limitation in ios for pwa!

```
const isIos = () => {
      const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      return /iphone|ipad|ipod/.test(userAgent);
    }
    const isInStandaloneMode = () => ('standalone' in window.navigator) && (window.navigator.standalone);
    if (isIos() && !isInStandaloneMode()) {
        var deferredPrompt;
        window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
          // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
          e.preventDefault();
          // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
          deferredPrompt = e;
              var display = true;
            setInterval(function () {
            document.getElementById("balloonMessage").style.display = display ? "none" : "block";
            display = !display;
          }, 5000);      
        });
    }
```

Comment: any solution for stopping multiple icons to add home screen ? am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

PWAs in iOS is not yet fully supported.  It can only do as much as offline caching but that's it.  Apple iOS's version of A2HS is still manual and most users don't even know that the feature existed.

If you want to trigger that A2HS banner, you will need to do a custom JavaScript event and pop up a custom A2HS HTML banner to "guide" your users on how to add the site on their home screen.

Answer (score -1):

You can use BeforeInstallPrompt for this. And warn user about adding new PWA.
criteria for BeforeInstallPrompt include the following:

- The web app is not already installed
- Meets a user engagement heuristic (currently, the user has interacted with the domain for at least 30 seconds)
- Meets the Progressive Web App criteria

Comment: I already tried this but it didn't work for me. Could you please help me with the code.

Comment: Push to git and shoot the link.

Comment: Do I need to write anything else apart from the above code.